# XMLHttpRequest in PAC file?

Tags: javascript, proxy, pac

It is possible to use XMLHttpRequest in firefox PAC file?

I write a little JS script that get proxy from one site api, but when I tried to use it I get error:

> XMLHttpRequest is not defined